# postgres sql insert into

Tags: postgresql

Tenho de copiar dados de duas base de dados para uma nova, acontece que quando copiou novos dados estes já existem mas existem novos que não são inseridos.

A query tenho tenho de momento é esta:

```
INSERT INTO concelho(id,censo,concelho)
SELECT "CONCELHO","CENSO","CONCELHO_DSG"
FROM dblink('dbname=meu_db host=meu_host user=meu_user password=minha_senha' ::text,'SELECT "CONCELHO","CENSO","CONCELHO_DSG" FROM "MUNICIPIO (Concelho)"' ::text,false) 
as tabela_temp("CONCELHO" varchar, "CENSO" varchar, "CONCELHO_DSG" character varying (200))
```

Comment: Oi user, enquanto um dblink para localhost é geralmente seguro (não fica exposto na Internet), tome cuidado para não postar usuários e senhas por aqui. Lembres-se que o conteúdo é indexado por buscadores e fica aberto na Internet.

Comment: Não entendi. Qual o problema? Dados duplicados são inseridos? Ou existem dados que simplesmente são ignorados? Há uma mensagem de erro?

Comment: sim ele verifica que ja existe um registo igual, mas nao coloca os diferentes

Answer (score 1):

ja resolvi

```
'INSERT INTO concelho(id,censo,concelho)´SELECT "CONCELHO","CENSO","CONCELHO_DSG"FROM dblink('dbname=meu_db host=meu_hostuser=meu_user password=minha_senha'::text,'SELECT"CONCELHO","CENSO","CONCELHO_DSG" FROM"MUNICIPIO (Concelho)"' ::text,false) as tabela_temp("CONCELHO" varchar,"CENSO" varchar, "CONCELHO_DSG" character varying (200))WHERE    NOT EXISTS (SELECT id,censo,concelho FROM concelho WHERE id = tabela_temp."CONCELHO" 
);'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into concelho(id,censo,concelho)
select "CONCELHO","CENSO","CONCELHO_DSG"
from dblink(
    'dbname=meu_db host=meu_host user=meu_user password=minha_senha' ::text,
    'SELECT "CONCELHO","CENSO","CONCELHO_DSG" FROM "MUNICIPIO (Concelho)"' ::text,false)
as tabela_temp("CONCELHO" varchar, "CENSO" varchar, "CONCELHO_DSG" character varying (200))
except
select "CONCELHO","CENSO","CONCELHO_DSG"
from concelho
```